# jsPDF Acroforms not working in Angular app

Tags: angular, jspdf

I've got an Angular 7 app and I want to generate some PDFs using jsPDF from it. I can generate text based PDFs with no problems but when I try to add an Acroform field the PDF is generated but the fields are missing. Here's the steps to reproduce the problem:

1. Create a new Angular app with Angular-CLI:

   > ng new jspdfTester
   >
   > cd jspdfTester
2. Install jspdf

   > npm install -s jspdf
3. Add jspdf code to the app.component.ts file

   ```
   import { Component } from '@angular/core';
   import * as jsPDF from 'jspdf';

   declare global {
     const TextField: any;
   }

   @Component({
     selector: 'app-root',
     templateUrl: './app.component.html',
     styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
   })
   export class AppComponent {
     title = 'jspdfTester';

     constructor() {
       const doc = new jsPDF();
       const textField = new TextField();
       textField.Rect = [50, 50, 30, 10];
       doc.addField(textField);
       doc.text('test', 50, 40);
       doc.save('sample.pdf');
     }
   }
   ```
4. Run the app and a PDF will download that contains the test text but no text field.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

**Edit:**
After careful debugging it looks like the Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor method from zone.js is being called instead of the browser's Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor method. Apparently they work differently and it's breaking jsPDF. Still no resolution but I'm getting closer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that zone.js overrides the Object.defineProperty setting and changes the configuration value of some of the properties that jsPDF tries to set when it is defining the AcroFrom prototypes. I am not sure if it's possible to work around this without a change to one of the two libraries. I have [proposed a change to jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/2429) so maybe in the next release they will fix it.